# Multiple join conditions using many collections, with pipeline mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**criteria to find**

```
{
  fullName: "aaaa bbb",
  order: 478
}
```

collection products.js:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
  firstNameProduct: "aaaa",
  secondNameProduct: "bbb"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c54d2f"),
  firstNameProduct: "aaaa",
  secondNameProduct: "kkk"
}
```

collection clients.js:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
  fullName: "aaaa bbb",
  order: 478
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf90ht44"),
  fullName: "aaaa www",
  order: 811
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf954fu2"),
  fullName: "aaaa bbb",
  order: 133
}
```

need find the product that matches that criteria, **expected result**:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
  firstNameProduct: "aaaa",
  secondNameProduct: "bbb"
}
```

How do i write the pipeline?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest to split the **fullName** into two (using code) & querying directly on products collection is much more efficient than doing any other thing, Have indexes on both `firstNameProduct` & `secondNameProduct` then you're good to go !!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  The best way to handle this is probably to update your document model.  You could change the clients collection to have both first and second name.

Alternatively, you could use an aggregation pipeline like the following:

```
[
    {$match: {fullName:"aaaa bbb", order:478}}, 
    {$lookup: {
    from: 'products',
    let: { productName: "$fullName"},
    pipeline: [
        {"$match": {
            $expr: {
            $and: [
                {$eq: ["$firstNameProduct", {"$arrayElemAt": [{"$split": ["$$productName", " "]}, 0]} ]},
                {$eq: ["$secondNameProduct", {"$arrayElemAt": [{"$split": ["$$productName", " "]}, 1]} ]}
                ]
            }
        }}],
    as: 'matchingProduct'
    }}
]
```

The lookup stage searches for products that match on firstNameProduct and secondNameProduct.  The result is an object that looks like the following:

```
_id:56d82612b63f1c31cf906003
name1:"aaaa"
name2:"bbb"
matchingProduct:Array
  0:Object
    secondNameProduct:"bbb"
    _id:5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd
    firstNameProduct:"aaaa"
order:478
```

You could add a $project stage to clean up the data if you needed to.

This pipeline assumes there will only be two products and they will be listed in the same order in both collections.

Comment: There could be an issue if user has `firstName middleName lastName` as `fullName` field, So the split can be tricky, if that's not the case then we're good :-)